# Prevent Double Booking PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysqli

Hello I am having trouble with a appointment booking database. I have been stuck on this for 3 days and I cant figure out what to do. I have appointments with various lengths that I retrieve from a form using PHP POST. I then try to update the database with the values I received. I want to stop users from double booking appointments and booking appointments while another one is going on.

This is my DB 
 [MYSQL DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo0zX.jpg).

The lesson_date_time field is in DATETIME format with a max value of 6.

The form code

```
<form method="post" name="update" action="dtupp.php" /> 
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
    Lesson Length:<br>   
    <input type="text" name="length" /><br> 
    Start Date<br> 
    <input type="text" name="date"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" /> 
</form>
```

The values I pass into the form are

For Start Date: 2014-11-30 12:41:00

For Lesson Length: 60

For Email: Fake@aol.com

My processor statement

```
<?php 
$mins = $_POST["length"];
$date_start = $_POST["date"];
$date_end   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$date_start + $mins minute"));
$emails = $_POST['emails']; 
mysql_connect("localhost", "dk1", "root1") or die("Connection Failed"); 
mysql_select_db("usersignup")or die("Connection Failed"); 
$query = " UPDATE bookings SET email = '$emails' WHERE lesson_date_time BETWEEN CAST('$date_start' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('$date_end' AS DATETIME) ";
if(!mysql_query($query)){
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{
}
?>
```

For some reason I cannot get the values to into the database. MYSQL doesn't return ANY ERRORS. I checked if the error reporting is working by misplacing quotes and MYSQL immediately flags me. It wont return any errors but wont post anything into the database either.

Comment: Note you have SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you trying to insert a new line or update one that's already there?

Comment: avoid booking when another booking is going ,you should be using concurrency control for that ?

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: I am trying to insert a value into the EMAIL field. But I think the code I have is for checking if the value fits between those times. If it does I DO NOT want to insert it into the database.

Comment: @Osuwariboy I am trying to update a line that is already there. This is a test DB and I will update my DB with more fields.

Comment: @rahultyagi Yes! You are correct. I think my current code is doing the opposite of what I want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing you're missing here is having a condition that prevents over-writing previous bookings. In the current state of things that will take the form:

```
UPDATE bookings SET ... WHERE email IS NULL
```

This presumes `email` is initially `NULL` which it should be. Avoid setting it to obtuse things like `'none'` or an empty string.

Note, you'll want to avoid violating the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) and adhere to proper [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) rules: Create a table that represents the individual making the booking. Even if this table only contains the email address at first, it's a huge step towards having proper database integrity.

Then you'd insert `user_id` instead, where that refers to a record in your `users` table. This way if a user changes their `email` address you only have to update one row, not N rows in who knows how many tables.

This establishes a proper "one-to-many" relationship between users and bookings. From there you can build out a very robust application.

Comment: Instead of email can I just have a hidden field in my form. With the word taken? That way anything appointment that is taken will have a column that says BOOKED or TAKEN.

So I just add and EXTRA where clause? So it would be 

$query = " UPDATE bookings SET email = '$emails' WHERE email  IS NULL AND lesson_date_time BETWEEN CAST('$date_start' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('$date_end' AS DATETIME) ";

Comment: It's generally best to have "taken" mean something specific, like `booking_id` is populated, or email address is non-NULL. Having a secondary indicator means you need to have two things in sync, and one could slip, causing inconsistency. Simpler is better here. Remember, trusting **any** form input is extremely risky, so a hidden field is not really going to cut it.

Comment: I tried adding the code that you suggested however I still do not upload anything. My Email field or my booking times are never uploaded. I do not understand what is going on. Shouldnt I be updating the first entry in the DB which has a blank for the email adress?

Comment: First you'd want to verify that `SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE ...` with the same clause actually selects rows. You may be trying to book with invalid conditions.

Comment: It is returning 0 rows. I think what is going is that I am doing the opposite of what I am trying to achieve. It is only letting me book lessons that are between those times. How can I reverse this code?

Comment: The `CAST` should be largely irrelevant by the way if you're using [ISO-8601 date formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If you want to invert it, try `NOT BETWEEN`? Also: `LIMIT 1`. Here's where generating a booking ID (e.g. random string, UUID) would help, since once you update a row you need to know *which* row you've updated.

Comment: Cant I just use the email as the UserID. For example WHERE $EMAIL=EMAIL

Comment: Ideally an ID is immutable, non-changing over the lifespan of the project and represents a particular user, not a particular address. Email addresses **do** change, so don't lock someone into a particular one.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there a no rows for your WHERE statement. For debugging check with SELECT if your WHERE statement returns anything.

You also could check the affected rows of your statement with [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

I also wanted to mention that you should be aware of sql injections!